# Qt Creator: No Debugger Set Up

Tags: debugging, qt-creator, windbg, visual-studio-2015

Have to ask this question once again here as none of the replies I found solve the issue.

So the goal is to set up the debugger for Qt Creator on Windows 8.1 x64. Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 (Community) and Qt 5.7 32-bit are installed on the system. As far as I understand I need Debugging Tools For Windows, which are a part of the Windows SDK. Visual Studio seems to install Windows SDK, but it doesn't have debugging tools. If I look into "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers" I see only one folder there, which is "x64" (and I suppose there must have been "x86" for 32-bit Qt). That folder contains three .dll files and no cdb.exe.

I tried to install Windows Debugging Tools manually as a part of Windows SDK, downloaded from [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk), but when I run the installer it gives me the error:
[image]

I guess that's because VS already has Windows SDK. Should I uninstall some component from Visual Studio? But I really don't want to break it.
[image]

Any help is appreciated